# XPath within document.evaluate returns empty if filtering by xml:id

Tags: javascript, xpath, xmlhttprequest, xmldom

I have this .xml:

```
[...]<person xml:id="pe_054">
                   <persName>
                      <forename>Robert</forename>
                      <surname>Thomas</surname>
                   </persName>
 </person>[etc]
```

I have this JavaScript:

```
[...]function resolver() {
return 'http://www.tei-c.org/ns/1.0';
}
Connect.open("GET", "data/persons_places.xml", false);
Connect.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "text/xml");
Connect.send(null);
var xmldoc = Connect.responseXML;
const surname = xmldoc.evaluate('//tei:person/tei:persName/tei:surname', xmldoc, resolver, XPathResult.STRING_TYPE, null)[...]
```

which works as expected, i.e. it returns the text content of the first 'surname' node. I need, though, to get a specific surname via the @xml:id attribute. Therefore, if I edit the XPath to this:

```
const surname = xmldoc.evaluate('//tei:person[@xml:id='pe_001']/tei:persName/tei:surname', xmldoc, resolver, XPathResult.STRING_TYPE, null)
```

the code returns an empty string. In the console.log I get:

```
XPathResult { resultType: 2, stringValue: "", invalidIteratorState: false }
```

`stringValue` does get populated if I don't filter by @xml:id. I'm at a loss: I tried making it workin by escapint the @, the brackets, the equals, nothing. Can anybody help me please?

Comment: Have you checked `const surname = xmldoc.evaluate("//tei:person[@xml:id='pe_001']/tei:persName/tei:surname", xmldoc, resolver, XPathResult.STRING_TYPE, null)` ? I see your resolver is handling `tei` but not sure about `xml`.

Comment: Hello, I'm not sure where your previous comment about the xpath being wrong and my reply to it ended up, they vanished. Anyway, you're rght about the namespace!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @supputuri I realised that it was just an issue with the xml namespace. So, the working code is:

```
function nsResolver(prefix) {
  var ns = {
    'xml' : 'http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace',
    'tei': 'http://www.tei-c.org/ns/1.0'
  };
  return ns[prefix] || null;
}
const Connect = new XMLHttpRequest();

Connect.open("GET", "data/persons_places.xml", false);
Connect.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "text/xml");
Connect.send(null);
var xmldoc = Connect.responseXML;
const surname = xmldoc.evaluate('string(//tei:person[@xml:id="pe_054"]/tei:persName/tei:surname)', xmldoc, nsResolver, XPathResult.STRING_TYPE, null)
```

Comment: Awesome! Glad that the comment helped you solving the issue.